# highlight selected row without loops

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have javascript that changes backcolors of selected rows. and for others row it uses two back colors for alternatives rows.
How can i achieve same with out loop given in javascript.

My aspx design page :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" Width="80%" BackColor="#3366FF">
                <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#6699FF" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var gridViewCtlId = '<%=GridView1.ClientID%>';
        var gridViewCtl = null;
        var curSelRow = null;
        var oddrowcolor = null;
        var evenrowcolor = null;
        function getGridViewControl() {
            if (null == gridViewCtl) {
                gridViewCtl = document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId);
            }
        }
        function onGridViewRowClick(rowIndex) {
            var table = document.getElementById("GridView1");
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 != 1) {
                    table.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#6699FF';
                }
                else {
                    table.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#3366FF';
                }
            }
            var selRow = getClickedRow(rowIndex);
            if (null != selRow) {
                selRow.style.backgroundColor = '#FFCC33';
            }
        }

        function getClickedRow(rowIndex) {
            getGridViewControl();
            if (null != gridViewCtl) {
                return gridViewCtl.rows[rowIndex];
            }
            return null;
        }
    </script>
```

And backend c# code :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int rowid = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.RowIndex) + 1;
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onGridViewRowClick('" + rowid.ToString() + "')");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Set the `BackColor="#3366FF"` on the `RowStyle` `<RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" BackColor="#3366FF" />`

Comment: mjw i want to remove the loops in javascript.